# how push vendor folder using pipeline bitbucket laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How push vendor folder using pipeline Bitbucket in Laravel?

This is a my bitbucket-pipelines.yml and project in Laravel. I try, but the vendor folder is not added to the server

```
image: php:7.2

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip && apt-get -qq install git-ftp
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_HOST
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Dont you have a log for the execution of this process? maybe your `composer install` is running into issues.

Comment: The composer install command is executed without errors and deploy too, but the vendor folder does not load on the server

Comment: then it cant have executed correctly. Try running your lines of code manually on the server (and with the same user) and see if you are getting errors. Maybe you're looking at the wrong directory its hard to tell.

Comment: I have found mistake/.

Comment: git ftp push --user $FTP_USERNAME --passwd $FTP_PASSWORD ftp://$FTP_HOST
Unknown SHA1 object, make sure you are deploying the right branch and it is up-to-date.
Do you want to ignore and upload all files again? [y/N]: Aborting...

Comment: I changed my yaml file from saying "git ftp push" to "git ftp push --force"